# How to have all other image buttons in group "reset" to previous image when a new button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

[a key http://www.bestmarketingnames.com/elementsDLS/art.jpg](http://www.bestmarketingnames.com/elementsDLS/art.jpg)[a key http://www.bestmarketingnames.com/elementsDLS/beauty.jpg](http://www.bestmarketingnames.com/elementsDLS/beauty.jpg)[a key http://www.bestmarketingnames.com/elementsDLS/business2.jpg](http://www.bestmarketingnames.com/elementsDLS/business2.jpg)

I have a web page with several "keys" like the above.  When the user clicks on one, 
I would like it to switch to a blue button image.  When the user clicks on a different 
key, I would like it to switch to blue and the others go back to grey.

There will be a total of about **30** keys.  They will also be hyperlinked.

I have found a semi-solution using css to create "buttons," but it works with IE and not chrome:
http://archive.simurai.com/lab/buttons/#

I would prefer to do it with image switching anyway, but css would be my second choice.

Can this be done without a giant mess?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery with `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` functions ... maybe something like this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("button").removeClass("blue");
    $(this).addClass("blue");
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N3wNm/1/)

and in the CSS you just need to make your `.blue` class style the blue image button.

**EDIT:** I added an example with image buttons, so you can get an idea: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N3wNm/4/)

Comment: Thank you Martin.  Can you tell me where the other styles for the buttons would go?  Also do you think this is a superior solution to using images?

Comment: in the css you have to set a `background-image` property, like this http://jsfiddle.net/N3wNm/2/ And you have to set up `:hover` and `:active` to achieve the whole button effect.

Comment: I'm starting to understand -- so do I need to use text to label the buttons as in your example, or can I use the button images I have already created that have the text in the image itself?

Comment: You can use just the images without additional text, although, text is sometimes safer as a fallback option. **Additional note:** it can be done on any element ... it does not need to be a `button` tag, I just used it for the simpler (no-image) example.

Comment: Here is an example with no text added to the buttons and with different tags (`a`,`span`,`div` displayed as `inline-block` to be nicely in one row): http://jsfiddle.net/N3wNm/7/

Comment: So if you had had each of the three items as a different unique image, you would have used 9 images right?  And each would require a separate class right?  (I don't use css or jquery very often so i'm not very familiar with how it works.)

Comment: I think your assumption is correct, the images including text would need to be specifically added for each state of each button ... but then you would want to use an `id` and not `class` to select the specific button ... however, I would recommend not to use too many images ... you could try using sprites (http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) ... but (as your buttons seem quite simple) I recommend drawing them in CSS http://jsfiddle.net/N3wNm/8/ Then you have way less code and work, for each button, and the fallback to text.